# Rails Routing to grandparent nested class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

I'm having a problem with a nested routing when I try to edit the subresource (lessons) from it's show page by clicking the edit link as described below. There are two classes involved: Units and Lessons. I can't understand why Rails is trying to route to course controller (a parent of Units).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**I am getting this error and url**

```
http://localhost:3000/units/3/lessons/13/edit
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"courses", :id=>nil}
```

**config/routes.rb**
    resources :courses do
        resources :units
    end

```
resources :units do
    resources :lessons
end
```

** from rake routes**

```
    unit_lessons GET    /units/:unit_id/lessons(.:format)            lessons#index
                 POST   /units/:unit_id/lessons(.:format)            lessons#create
 new_unit_lesson GET    /units/:unit_id/lessons/new(.:format)        lessons#new
edit_unit_lesson GET    /units/:unit_id/lessons/:id/edit(.:format)   lessons#edit
     unit_lesson GET    /units/:unit_id/lessons/:id(.:format)        lessons#show
```

**code for clicked link**

```
<%= link_to "Edit Lesson", edit_unit_lesson_path(@unit, @lesson ) %>
```

**LessonsController**

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_unit
  before_filter :find_lesson, :only => [:show,:edit,:update,:destroy]
  .
  .
  .
private
def find_unit
  @unit = Unit.find(params[:unit_id])
end

def find_lesson
  @lesson = @unit.lessons.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Server Log File**

```
Started GET "/units/3/lessons/12/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-02 14:50:55 +0200
Processing by LessonsController#edit as HTML
    Parameters: {"unit_id"=>"3", "id"=>"12"}
    Unit Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "units".* FROM "units" WHERE "units"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
Lesson Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "lessons".* FROM "lessons" WHERE "lessons"."unit_id" = 3 AND     "lessons"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "12"]]
Rendered lessons/_form.html.erb (3.4ms)
Rendered lessons/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (4.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"courses", :id=>nil}):
app/views/lessons/edit.html.erb:8:in   `_app_views_lessons_edit_html_erb___3830769233446763788_70188197130200'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The link was part of a table body, built with an .each iterator. I needed to change the name from "@lesson" to "lesson" as that is what is referenced when the table is built.

For anyone else stuck on a similar problem, I've put the functioning code below.

```
<tbody>  
  <% @unit.lessons.each do |lesson| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to lesson.lesson_name, [@unit, lesson] %></td>
      .
      .
      .
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_unit_lesson_path(@unit, lesson ) %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
 </tbody>
```